# Drawing call function diagrams using pyan results in the diagram of just one python file

Tags: python-3.x, diagram, function-call

I'm trying to draw function call diagram for a complicated functional python code including many python files and related functions across them. I managed to make use of pyan tool to draw call diagram, but it just do it for a single *.py file and does not take into consideration the whole code and functions. Do you think there is an option to make it work for the whole code base?

```
pyan3 app.py  --uses --no-defines --colored --grouped --annotated --dot > app_diagram.dot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob pattern `**/*.py`. From the [repository](https://github.com/Technologicat/pyan/blob/350ea49687b93d5b31afa0778ccf732b6151f874/pyan/__init__.py#L36):

```
filenames: glob pattern or list of glob patterns
            to identify filenames to parse (`**` for multiple directories)
            example: **/*.py for all python files
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, cathei. A handy answer solved my problem and I accepted your answer. It does draw the diagram for all the files but does not show the relationship between functions in different files. Are there any options to show the relationships between the functions of different files?

Comment: @f.ashouri It has 'uses' relationship and 'defines' relationship, but you are using '--no-defines' flag which prevent defines relationship to be drawn.